# Large scale linearly-constrained convex quadratic optimization - R/Python/Gurobi

Tags: large-data, gurobi, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a series of **linearly-constrained convex quadratic optimization** problems that have around **100.000 variables**, **1 linear constraint** and **100.000 bound constraints** (the same as the number of variables - the solution has to be positive). I am planning to use [gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/) in R and/or Python. I have noticed that, although for small problems the solver can find a solution quite quickly, for medium to large problems (as the one I have), it takes forever (some benchmarks are shown in [here](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html) - credits to Stéphane Caron).

I know that qp methods do not scale very well, but I'd like to know if you are aware of any solver/technique/tool that solves medium to large qp problems faster.

Thanks!

[Please click here to see the optimization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATy3P.png)

Comment: I'd be curious to see your optimization problem written in more detail.

Comment: Hi littleO, I've just added a picture containing the optimization problem. Specifically, n is 100.000 and Q is positive semidefinite. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Why is the optimization variable called $W_{1:n}$ and not just $w$?

Comment: What does $e_n$  denote? Is it the $n$th standard basis vector? Is it just an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Thanks littleO. It's a vector of variables of dimension n (that's why $W_{1:n}$), and $e_n$ is just a vector of 1s. The linear constraint is just constraining the sum of the variables to be equal to n (the size of the vector).

Comment: For large scale problems people often use first-order methods rather than interior point methods. This problem could be solved using the projected gradient method (or an accelerated projected gradient method such as FISTA). To do this, the key step is to express your problem as minimizing f(w) subject to w \in S, where S is the probability simplex. Both of your constraints are combined into that single constraint x \in S. It is possible to project onto the probability simplex efficiently. (That's not obvious, but you can Google for how to do that.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you say what application you're working on that led to this problem?

Comment: Here's a math.stackexchange thread with a reference and link to code for projecting onto the probability simplex: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/projecting-a-non-negative-vector-onto-the-simplex

Comment: @littleO Out of curiousity (did not touch num-opt recently): box-projection is trivial, simplex-projection is well-researched: but supporting box-constraints and the probability-simplex should lead to some joint-projection: this requires *some thought*, or not? **edit:** ah, he only needs non-negativity, so it's already part of the simplex-projection.

Comment: I second the proposed projection-approach (although there is some implementation overhead and you probably will need line-search e.g. armijo), but you also might try some low-cost experiment: use cvxpy with the [SCS solver](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs) which is ADMM-based and might work better than your current ones. You might need to tune it's settings (e.g. direct or **indirect** solving of sparse linear sys)

Comment: I am not worried about 100k variables. But a dense Q matrix of 100k x 100k is large.